# Properties of Product Measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> **A question**
>
> Let $\mathbb{P}_X,\mathbb{P}_Y,\mathbb{P}_Z$ be the law of three random variables. If $\mathbb{P}_X=\mathbb{P}_Y$ then,
>
> are $\mathbb{P}_X \otimes \mathbb{P}_Z=\mathbb{P}_Y \otimes \mathbb{P}_Z$?

where  $\mathbb{P}_X \otimes \mathbb{P}_Z$ is the product measure of the Tonelli-Fubini Theorem

Comment: ah, yes. Thank you.

Comment: the answer is trivially yes, assuming that the equal sign in the expression $\mathbb{P}_X=\mathbb{P}_Y$ means that they are equal measures defined in the same measure space

Comment: So I can state they are equal under the assumptions you mentioned given the uniqueness of the extension, right?